# How to check if value exist in an array or return next free index

Tags: c, arrays

I'm trying to write an efficient function that takes value as an input and check for that value in an array. If value exist in an array, then return index for that value in an array. Else if the value doesn't exist, then return the next free index in an array.
In main function, I would like to write to one of the following index return by getIndex()
 - At either the index returned by the getIndex
 - or next free index.

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct Section {
int numOfStudents;
} Section;


typedef struct School {
   int schoolId;
   int numberofSections;
   Section sections[5];
} School;

School school_1[4]; // array that hold the values

int getIndex(int  schoolAddressInfo)
{
  int empty_index[4] = {-1,-1,-1,-1}; //array to hold next free index
  int rIndex = -1; // index to return
  int i,j,k;

  for ( i = 0; i < 4; i++)
  { 
    if (school_1[i].schoolId == 0) // if the index in array school_1 doesn't contain any data i.e default value = 0, mark that index
    {
      empty_index[i] = i;
    }
    else if (school_1[i].schoolId == schoolAddressInfo) // check if value exist in an array, if it does return the index
    {
      rIndex = i;
      return rIndex;      
      break; // break once element found, don't need to go through rest of the array
    }   
  } 
  // if the value is not found, return first free index out of indexs saved in empty_index
  for ( j = 0; j < 4; j++)
  { 
    if (empty_index[j] != -1)
    {
      rIndex = empty_index[j];    
      return rIndex;      
      break;
    }
  }  
  return rIndex;
}

//function to populate the array that hold values i.e school_1[]
void populateSchool(){
    int i,j;
    for(i=0; i < 4; i++)
    {
       school_1[i].schoolId = 0;
       school_1[i].numberofSections = 0;
       for (j=0;j<5;j++){
         school_1[i].sections[j].numOfStudents = 0;
        }

    }
    school_1[0].schoolId = 21;
    school_1[1].schoolId = 22;
    school_1[3].schoolId = 23;
   }

int main ()
{
  int i,y,z;
  int schoolId = 25;
  populateSchool(); //populate the array with either default or real values
  int index = getIndex(schoolId); //check if schoolId already exist, if it doesn't exist, create new index, else update existing index

  for (i=0; i< 5; i++)
  {
    school_1[index].sections[i].numOfStudents = 20;
  }

  for ( y = 0; y < 5; y++ )
  {
    printf("school_1[%d].sections[%d].numOfStudents= %d\n",     index,y,school_1[index].sections[y].numOfStudents );
  }
   return 0;
}
```

This code works but I'm wondering if getIndex() can be optimized further. 
For e.g getting the same result without using 2 for loops.

Comment: What do you mean by `an efficient way`? Also, your code is not that big to worry about.

Comment: if you usr return statement then you dont have to use break. it will leave the function right away.

`rIndex = i;
      return rIndex;      
      break;`

you can directly use `return i;`

Comment: @SKD By efficient I meant if it can further optimized. Perhaps it wasn't very clear. I have edited a bit to make it more clear

Comment: @Grv good catch :). Didn't realise that

Answer (score 0):

One possible way without having to use another for loop

```
int getIndex(int  schoolAddressInfo)
{
  int rIndex = -1; // index to return
  int i;
  bool firstFreeIndexFound = false;

  for ( i = 0; i < 4; i++)
  { 
    if (school_1[i].schoolId == schoolAddressInfo) // check if value exist in an array, if it does return the index
    {
      rIndex = i;
      return rIndex; //don't need to go through rest of the array   
    }
    else if (school_1[i].schoolId == 0 && firstFreeIndexFound!=true) // if the index in array school_1 doesn't contain any data i.e default value = 0, mark that index
    {
      rIndex = i;
      firstFreeIndexFound = true;
    }
  }  
  return rIndex;
}
```